# Can't initialize primefaces in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to start primefaces in my spring boot project but the URI just doesn't work
**this is the file I want to display**

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>


<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h1>hi</h1>
    <p:spinner />
</h:body>
</html>
```

**These are the dependencies needed**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to fetch external resources but an error always pops up

> No XML at the specified location: http://primefaces.org/ui

Comment: Try using JoinFaces if you want Spring Boot + PrimeFaces: http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: Can you post all the pom.xml or your spring boot configuration?